# Recreate RAID1 after upgrade to 16.04--mdadm help

Tags: upgrade, raid, mdadm

I recently upgraded my system from 14.04 to 16.04.  I stuck the DVD in the drive and chose Upgrade.  The upgrade appears to be good.

Before upgrading my system I had 4 drives in the computer.

```
/dev/sda1  Solid state drive mounted at / 
/dev/sdb1  1 TB disk mounted at /home
/dev/sdc1  2 TB disk mounted at /backup
/dev/sdd1  1 TB disk, mirror of sdb1 created with mdadm
```

However the RAID1 did not survive the upgrade process.  Neither `sdb1` nor `sdd1` is mounted.  In fact, the `mdadm` command itself did not survive the upgrade and had to be installed separately.  So I must manually re-create the array.  I put the output of `mdadm --examine /dev/sdb` and `mdadm --examine /dev/sdd` into 2 files and did a `diff` on them.  Here is the output:

```
~# diff /tmp/sdd1 /tmp/sdb1
1c1
< /dev/sdd1:
---
> /dev/sdb1:
18c18
<     Device UUID : 3b7b057f:568cc19b:a978b944:cb3959cb
---
>     Device UUID : d2eb6d6e:12153cf5:e26cf1b8:44ab8647
20,22c20,22
<     Update Time : Tue Jun 30 21:38:12 2015
<        Checksum : d7244c7c - correct
<          Events : 1122
---
>     Update Time : Sat Jan 13 23:16:09 2018
>        Checksum : 16c57f3c - correct
>          Events : 26235816
25,26c25,26
<    Device Role : Active device 0
<    Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
---
>    Device Role : Active device 1
>    Array State : .A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Of course the UUID's will be different. The whole thing looks healthy to me. I just need the arguments to the `mdadm` command to recreate `/dev/md0` from `sdb1` and `sdd1`.

I'm an experienced *nix admin but I have little experience with `mdadm`.  I don't want to overwrite either drive.  Yes I have full backups but don't want to bother with that. I just want to have some confidence in knowing precisely the commands I need to re-create the RAID and notify the operating system to start the mirroring task again.

Comment: What is the output of  `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` ?

There are quite a few threads that explain how to rebuid md0, here's one: https://serverfault.com/questions/821966/how-to-re-add-a-drive-when-raid-is-in-degraded-mode